# Activity/Audit log for Azure Graph API used inside the Active Directory Application

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

**Background:** We have developed an Active Directory Enterprise Application. This application is developed to read free/busy information from the outlook calendar of a user in active directory. This application uses the [Get Schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) Graph API to get the free/busy information of the user. The authentication mechanism is via admin consent.

**Problem:** We have a client who is going to use this application and install it in their active directory. They want to see on their side the activity/operations which are being performed by this application using the Graph API. I am not sure if it is possible to get activity performed by each installed application. I know there is a way to know who installed/authorized the actual application but beyond that I do not see a way on Azure portal to see the logs for each API call.

In short, the client wants to know each API call that the enterprise application is making and validate that it is not fetching data that is sensitive.

Appreciate any guidance here.

**Update - 11/17/2020**

After reaching out to Microsoft Support through various channels we finally got an answer mentioning that it is not possible to obtain the information that we are looking for. There is no way to audit the usage of graph APIs mentioned above.

Regards,
Bhavik

Answer (score 0):

At least from the perspective of Azure AD, Microsoft has not provided such tools or methods to accomplish this.

It appears that your client is very worried that a person from other tenants (for example, your tenant) will access their company's data through this enterprise application. I think your client does not understand how the enterprise app works.

When your enterprise application is installed into his tenant via admin consent, it means that they could use this enterprise application to access their own data within the scope of this application. But as the developer, you have no access to their data. Any other tenants who are using your enterprise application will also not able to access other tenants' data.

Multi-tenant app is used to offer a Software as a Service (SaaS) application to many organizations. Clients' data is accessed in their own tenant. Learn more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant).

Besides, the enterprise application should follow the "least privilege principle", so if your app is only assigned `Calendars.Read` based on [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), it won't be able to get data other than Calendars data.

Comment: We have mentioned to them that we are using only Calendars.Read, and Calendars.ReadWrite (for create event scenario) permission. But they want to know two things:1) We are not accessing more data than we should even as a part of the response of the getSchedule API. For example, body of the calendar event. 2) How can they track what APIs we have called and if there is any auditing of the APIs that we have called and data it returned?

Comment: @BhavikBhagat You mean that you need to access their data? As I know the multi-tenant app allows them to access their own data, rather than allowing you to access their data. Microsoft Graph doesn't provide a method to track API calls. I guess you need to pay attention to some 3rd-party tool.

Comment: Yes, we need to access the free/busy schedule of the user and based on the response take some action. We even explored PowerShell cmdlets to see if there is a way to get some form of audit or access related information. But we haven't been successful yet. Is there any 3rd party tool that you know of?

Comment: @BhavikBhagat I've no idea about which 3rd party tool can do this. Just get a confirm from Azure support that Microsoft doesn't expose any api or tool to make it. Could you tell me how you access their data? What auth flow do you use? Auth code flow or client credential flow?

Comment: we use OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) where we request consent from the Admin for the scopes that we are going to use. Once Global Admin of the client grants the consent, we use the Microsoft graph API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can secure the process by limiting the answers received from the graph api to the customer tenant only, with the token reply url.
that way ,answers will only be accepted to requests made from the customer domain.
regarding the auditing, it's not perfect but you can monitor http requests to the api address with curl or 3rd party tool , and log the relevant api requests.
it will give them a sense of what going on behind the curtain.